# Calling function from macro inside Quicklisp package

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

I put **failing.asd**

```
(in-package :asdf-user)                    

(defsystem "failing"                       
  :description "some code destined to fail"
  :version "0.1"                           
  :author "me"                      
  :components ((:file "package")))
```

and **package.lisp**

```
(defpackage :failing  
  (:export :foo :bar))

(in-package :failing) 

(defun foo () 42)     

(defmacro bar ()      
  (let ((x (foo)))    
    `(print ,x)))     

(bar)
```

into **~/quicklisp/local-projects/failing**. Using Clozure CL with Quicklisp installed, I run

```
(ql:quickload :failing)
```

which gives me

```
To load "failing":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    failing
; Loading "failing"
[package failing]
> Error: Undefined function FOO called with arguments () .
> While executing: BAR, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Retry applying FOO to NIL.
> Type :? for other options.
```

It seems I can't call a function from a macro inside the package. Why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can only happen when the file gets compiled before loaded. Generally it has nothing to do with ASDF (which is a tool to manage file dependencies and to compile/load code) or packages (which are namespaces and are not in any way related to ASDF).

**It has to do with how file compilation works in Common Lisp**:

The *file compiler* sees the function `foo` and compiles it -> the code for it gets written to a file. **It does not (!) load the code into the compile-time environment.**

The *file compiler* then sees the macro bar and compiles it -> the code gets written to a file. **It does (!) load the code into the compile-time environment.**

The *file compiler* then sees the macro form `(bar)` and wants to expand it. It calls the macro function `bar`. Which calls `foo`, which is undefined, since it is not in the compile-time environment.

**Solutions**:

- put the function definition in a separate file in the ASDF system and compile/load it earlier.
- put the function inside the macro as a local function
- put `(EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL :LOAD-TOPLEVEL :EXECUTE) ...)` around the function definition. It causes the definition to be executed at compile-time.

**Remember**: the *file compiler* needs to know macro functions -> otherwise it would not be able to macroexpand code. Ordinary functions just get compiled, but not loaded at compile time, during compilation of a file.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. As a side-question, why are packages so complicated in Common Lisp? Intuitively I imagine that when I want to write modular code, I just split it up into files and then import the right file. This is how it happens in e.g. Python. Is there something in Common Lisp's DNA that makes this impossible?

Comment: @slimetree: we are talking about a ccmbination of macros and file compilation. Vanilla python does not provide that.